# When to use forget and forgot

Tags: tense

I just want to know when should I use the following two:

1. I forget
2. I forgot

For example, I had to call someone, but I didn't remember to call.

So, what should I use:
"I forget to call you" or "I forgot to call you"

Comment: *I forget to call you* sounds like a routine, a permanent action, so regarding the past tense *I had to call someone,* I'd use *I forgot to call you.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"I forgot"* can describe something that happened in the past.

> *I wanted to call my mother yesterday, but **I forgot** her phone number.*
>
> *Sorry I don't have your shirt.  I **forgot to** put it in my backpack before I came over.*
>
> ---

*"I forget"* can be used to describe a recurrent or continuous state.

> ***I forget** my lunch almost every day, and end up buying from the cafeteria.*
>
> ***I forget** people's names very easily - remind me of yours?*
>
> ---

*"I forget"* is also often used as a stand alone to reflect the current knowledge of the speaker with regards to some piece of information.  This is a little informal.

> `Q:` *What's the capital of France?*  `A:`***I forget.**  Maybe Grenoble?*
>
> **I forget** that guy's name - remind me?

Comment: I would have given you a upvote but I don't have a voting privilege yet.

Comment: Should you say ''I am always forgetting my lunch almost everyday'', than just ''forget''. I think this is more appropriate.

Comment: @JohnArvin You could say _"I am always forgetting my lunch."_ (informal) or _"I forget my lunch almost everyday"_  but not _"I am always forgetting almost every day."_

Comment: @Adam, why is that "I am always forgetting my lunch almost everyday" incorrect? Could you make it clear

Comment: @johnarvin I think that is a subtle/complicated enough issue to merit it's own SE question, rather than being poorly addressed in a comment on another question.

Answer (score 2):

*I forget to call you* sounds like a routine or permanent action. (Direct application of the present simple tense.)
So regarding the past tense *I had to call someone*, I'd use *I forgot to call you.*

Answer (score 0):

When you say "I had to call someone" you speak of an event in past time. Then you can only say "But I forgot to call him". You forgot the phone call in past time, not now.